# Android:Operate UI controls in other thread,but

Tags: java, android

```
beginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PlayThread playThread = new PlayThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(playThread);

        thread.start();
    }
});

public class PlayThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        beginButton.setClickable(false);
        pauseButton.setClickable(true);
        messageBool = true;
        int maxProgressBar = playProgressBar.getMax();
        int currentInt = playProgressBar.getProgress();

        for(; currentInt <= maxProgressBar; ++currentInt)
        {
            if(messageBool == false)
            {
                break;
            }
            playProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(currentInt > maxProgressBar)
        {
            playProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            beginButton.setClickable(true);
            pauseButton.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Hi,everyone. Is there any problem about this code? I know we **cannot** operate the UI's controls in other threads except *UI thread* . But this code runs **OK**.So what's wrong or is there something I miss? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: His problem is Why it is working fine in non-UI thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're safe if you don't modify the `View` in such way that it needs to be redrawn on the screen. `setClickable` only modifies one of its properties if you were, for example, to set the text or modify the `LayoutParams` of that `View`, action which will invalidate the `View`, the dreaded exception *Touched from the wrong thread...etc* will appear.

The `ProgressBar` is thread safe and can be used from any thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But how can I know which kind of view is thread safe? Or which kind of operation is thread safe for Button or others?

Comment: @ZhaoRocky If I'm not mistaken, the `ProgressBar` is the only `View` that can be used in every thread. Regarding the attributes, there isn't a rule, the key is to not invalidate the `View`(if you look at the source code for that particular view you would see setting which attribute will cause the `View` to invalidate). Anyway, you shouldn't be doing this, for example, in your code, the only part that need to be in the `run` method is the `for` loop with the `Thread.sleep()`. When it's time to post the result just use a `Handler`.